# Convert multiband GeoTIFF to dataframe using all bands (R, Python or QGIS)

Tags: python, r, geotiff-tiff, multi-band, data-frame

I have a GeoTIFF file with 2 bands and I want to create a dataframe like this:

```
pixelID | band1Value | band2Value
```

I would like to do it in R, Python or QGIS.
As far as what I have searched, I could only find for cases working with single bands.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to focus on one environment (R, since that's the answer you accepted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, use the `raster` package and `as.data.frame`:

Make a quick sample two-layer raster object:

```
> library(raster)
> r1 = raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))
> r2 = raster(matrix(sample(12),3,4))
> s = stack(r1,r2)
```

And so:

```
> as.data.frame(s)
   layer.1 layer.2
1        1      12
2        4       6
3        7       2
4       10       5
5        2       3
6        5      10
7        8       7
8       11       1
9        3       4
10       6       9
11       9      11
12      12       8
```

Read a two-band GeoTIFF with something like `s = stack("twolayers.tiff")`.